# How to handle too much element in a card (for a online food delivery site)

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-centered-design, human-interface-guideline

I am designing a food delivery site. and when its about to the design of card design . its have too much element(information), I was about to omit some things, but my boss is not ready to omit the things like (offers, distance in km, delivery charges, delivery time,delivery distance range etc.) from the card...

i got these much things, which i should have to keep in the card

1. Restaurant brand and name
2. Ratings / review
3. Delivery type(home deliver/ pickup)
4. Restaurant address
5. Restaurant timing status (open / closed)
6. Offers (## % Discount / off)
7. Minimum cost of order
8. Delivery distance
9. Delivery charges
10. Delivery ranges(in km)
11. Delivery time in avg

    I am damn messed up with these data . I think it can be minimal , and using upper data i designed it bellow but i think its not user friendly and i am not satisfied with it.

[image]

**If you have better ideas to improvement the design by making it minimal as well as user friendly please suggest.**

Comment: When I saw your design, the only confiusing part was the "open" sign, my first tought was that it is opening a map to show location on it. It is close to adress so it sims to be realated to location. 
Maybe somthing like "is open now"? Or add icon of open doors? (padlock for close)

Comment: yes notable issue. i will rectify the thing. Apart from these any issue in your vision ?

Comment: I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can I just say that I think you've done a damn good job? Considering the amount of information you need to have on the card, I personally see no issues in terms of UX and the card does make sense.

Only thing I'd suggest is ensure your contrast ratio for the delivery/pickup options and anything else you might have in grayscale check out!

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your design, the only confusing part was the "open" sign. Initially I thought it is a button that open a map to show location of the restaurant. It is close to address so it sims to be related to location. 
Maybe improving wording would do, like "is open now"? Or add icon of open doors? (padlock for close). Also, since it is button shape, I would suggest that if somebody click it, it should show opening hours.

The rest look good for me.